# SQL even splitting

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I have this table

```
hh_potential_offers
```

It contains customer_IDs with potential offers they can receive

```
select offer, count(customer_id) as customers from hh_potential_offers  group by 1  ;

Offer   Customers 
offer1  807708
offer2  4986267
offer3  3045273
```

I need to assign each customer_id to a single offer. Within these tables, each customer can either have 1 potential offer or any amount ( in this case 2 or 3 but there can be even 10 offers for a particular week )

For the overlaps, I would like them to go to the offers that have less potential customers, in this scenrio for example, offer 1 only has 800k where offer 2 and 3 have 4 & 3M. I want to make sure all the overlapping customers get assigned to offer 1 as we need to ensure that each offer dosent get too little reach. after offer 1 is prioritised, then offer 3 would as it is still less than offer 2. This can get quiet complicated when there are many offers.

I was thinking ideally, that the least amount offer can "take" from the most amount offer in the overlaps, and then a calculation can be done until there is a most even distribution, but can get complicated with many offers.

How should I approach assigning customer_ids to their offer with the requirements I said above?

I'd like to insert this data into a third table

The input data would look like this:

```
select * from hh_potential_offers limit 7

Offer   Customer_id
Offer 2     6565233
Offer 3     6565233
Offer 2     357652
Offer 1     76782
Offer 2     854342
Offer 3     2168
Offer 1     2168
```

Expected result would be inserting into a table lets say table assigned_offers and would look something like

```
Customer_ID Offer
2168    Offer 1 
76782   Offer 1
6565233 Offer 3
854342  Offer 2 
357652  Offer 2
```

Keep in mind, this is just dummy data, I don't know what the exact assignment would be of these offers based on whatever calculations are best to make even assignment of the offers. Just trying to find the best way to assign households to an offer and ensuring overlaps are prioritised to those with less potential so there is as even as possible distribution

Comment: What's input data? Use text instead of images.

Comment: Okay I updated to have text instead of images - that is some sample data

Comment: You forgot to show your input data... :) This does not have to be original data. You should post expected result too.

Comment: Okay I added some things at the bottom - I don't know if the expected output I wrote would truly be that, as there are millions of rows of data, so based on whatever calculations - the true assignment for customer id to its offer would occur